# Getting python.exe path at run time

Tags: python

On Windows, how do I find the path to python.exe from within a script at runtime?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Program Files\\Python31\\pythonw.exe'
```