# Finding python.exe programmatically in python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting python.exe path at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846888/getting-python-exe-path-at-run-time)

I have a python app that launches other apps with explicit calls to C:\python25\python.exe, but this doesn't work if the user has 2.6 installed or if they have it installed to another location. There is a %PYTHON% variable for the exe, but this is only available to the user who installed Python (other users don't have this envvar set).

Is there another way to look up this location?

Comment: Any reason you don't change your code to invoke `python.exe` instead of `C:\python25\python.exe`?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846888/getting-python-exe-path-at-run-time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import sys
print sys.executable
```

Comment: Is there anything sys can't do? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Program Files\\Python31\\pythonw.exe'
```

Comment: I beat you by 17 secs :P

Comment: it took me time to open IDLE ;)

Comment: 17 seconds cause five people to upvote nosklo's answer and not upvote this one. (shakes head) +1 to both

Comment: I don't  think it's correct Graeme, all votes were cast after recursive's answer.

Comment: My point was that your answer and nosklo's answer were posted 17 seconds apart, and say almost *exactly* the same (correct) thing, yet his answer has 5 more (at the time - 4 more now) upvotes than this one.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`execfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile).  This executes the script you want using the same python instance that's already running.

Comment: Not downvoting. But I consider this bad advice, what's the advantage of using execfile in this case (above a regular 'import')?

Comment: It connotes executing the file rather than importing a library.  What is the disadvantage?

Comment: My software launches many instances of python, being to use execfile would help restore sanity to my list of running processes.

Comment: Can command line arguements be passed?